# How to solve this limit to +∞?

Tags: limits

It`s very important for me to calculate this limit, but I dont know how, even from what to start.

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}{(x-\sqrt{x-1}\ln(x^2+e^{\sqrt{x}})} $$

Hope you will help me with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the dominant term in the argument of the logarithm is $e^{\sqrt{x}}$ so that

$$\sqrt{x-1}\ln(x^2 +e^{\sqrt{x}}) \approx \sqrt{x-1}\ln(e^{\sqrt{x}})  \approx\sqrt{x^2-x}\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little more rigour to the answer provided. You can evaluate the derivative and show that the function is montonically increasing.